# Using multiple group_concats and group by on the same field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am trying to write a query that tracks the occurrences over a one-month span, with each day of the month being a column of the result.  When trying to use group_concat for each day of the month, only the date of the first occurrence is returned.  I've included the schemas and data of the 2 tables that I'm working with below, as well as the result that I expect to see and the SQL query that I've tried.

Note: I've simplified the data and schema as much as possible to get to the root of the question.

Tracking

```
tracking_id  |  date
_______________________________________
1            |  2017-05-01
2            |  2017-05-02
```

TrackingStatus

```
trackingstatus_id  |  tracking_id  |  time
___________________________________________
1                  |  1            |  09:00
2                  |  2            |  10:00
3                  |  2            |  14:00
```

Desired Result

```
Month  | Day1   |  Day2
5      | 09:00  |  10:00,14:00
```

I tried the following query

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(date),
    if( date = '2017-05-01', group_concat(timeadministered), NULL ),
    if( date = '2017-05-02', group_concat(timeadministered), NULL )
FROM trackingstatus ts
JOIN tracking t ON t.tracking_id = ts.tracking_id
GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

But am getting the following result

```
Month  | Day1               |  Day2
5      | 09:00,10:00,14:00  |
```

I know that when I use the group by on the date, only the first date value is recognized by the row.  Is there a better way to go about this then using group by and group_concat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want an aggregate function *around* the expressions in the SELECT list. But wrapping another aggregate around GROUP_CONCAT doesn't make a lot of sense, since the expression in the GROUP BY clause means you will only get back one row for each month.

Maybe you are wanting something like this:

```
 SELECT MONTH(t.date)
      , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(t.date = '2017-05-01',t.timeadministered,NULL)) AS Day01
      , GROUP_CONCAT(IF(t.date = '2017-05-02',t.timeadministered,NULL)) AS Day02

  FROM ...
 GROUP BY MONTH(t.date)
```

---